# Calculated field with two collections

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I would like to know when I will be able to use my own functions to create a calculated field inside Cypher.

Let me give you an example of what I want :

```
START a=node(0)
MATCH path=a-[rel*1..3]->b
WITH path,b,extract(r in RELATIONSHIPS(path) : r.property1) as Collection1,extract(r in RELATIONSHIPS(path) : r.property2) as Collection2
RETURN b,Collection1,Collection2
```

It will give me something like :

```
Collection1 :             | Collection2 :
[property1.1,property1.2] | [property2.1,property2.2]
[property1.1]             | [property2.1]
etc.
```

I would like to add a field with property1.1*property2.1+property1.2*property2.2 and some others functions (like exp() and ln(), they are in cypher2.0 right?).
Is it possible to do it today with cypher ?
I know that there is the function Reduce() but how can I do to go through 2 collections at the same time ?

If I could call my own function, that would help me : something like "myFunction([collection1],[collection2]) as myResult".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree the support for user-defined function would be very helpful. But for many cases, there might be alternatives to reach the goal. Specific to your case, it seems you want to do calculations based on the properties of each relationship. So instead of retrieving relationships as a collection of relationships on a path, you might return each relationship as an indiviual row, and then process these relationship rows.

For example, the following query returns the sum of the multiplications of relationship properties p1 and p2,

```
START a=node(0)
MATCH path=a-[rel*1..3]->b
with last(relationships(path)) as r
With r.p1 * r.p2 as mul
Return sum(mul)
```

For this specific problem, since the properties p1 and p2 come from the same relationship, there actually is a very easy way to do it,just as what you already did,

```
START a=node(0)
MATCH path=a-[rel*1..3]->b
With b, extract(r IN RELATIONSHIPS(path):r.p1 * r.p2) AS mulCol
Return b, reduce((sum = 0, mul in mulCol: sum + mul)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to do that but for each relations of the path and not only the last one.

Comment: For instance,if there are 2 relations in the path, I want  R.p11 * R.p12 + R.p21*R.p22. If there are 3 relations, I want : R.p11 * R.p12 + R.p21*R.p22 + R.p31*R.p32 (with pab, a as the number of the relation and b as the number of the property). What you suggest is : R.p21*R.p22 or R.p31*R.p32. How I do with the previous relations ? I need them.

Comment: It retrieves last relationship of every returned path. Since every returned path is the last returned path plus a new relationship, it actually retrieves all relationships between the start node and the end node. For example, for a path between a->b->c->d, the query for the "Match path=a-[rel:*1..3]->d" would return the paths, a->b, a->b->c, and a->b->c->d. so by retrieving the last relationship of each returned path, you actually get all the relationships from a to d rather than the last relationship of a to d.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see. Let's try on the neo4j console :

```
CREATE (a { name:'a' }),(b { name:'b' }),(c { name:'c' }),(d { name:'d' }),(e { name:'e' }),(f { name:'f' }), a-[:RELATION { p1:1,p2:10 }]->b, a-[:RELATION { p1:2,p2:2 }]->d, b-[:RELATION { p1: 3,p2:5 }]->c, c-[:RELATION { p1: 2,p2:5 }]->e,d-[:RELATION { p1: 1,p2:6 }]->e, d-[:RELATION { p1: 4,p2:5 }]->f
```

Let's try my query :

```
START a=node:node_auto_index(name='a')
MATCH path = a-[R*1..3]->b 
WITH b,extract(r IN RELATIONSHIPS(path):r.p1) AS collection_p1,extract(r IN RELATIONSHIPS(path):r.p2) AS collection_p2 
RETURN b,collection_p1,collection_p2
```

I need that but with one more field : if there are 2 relations in the path, I need (collection_p1[1]*collection_p2[1] + collection_p1[2]*collection_p2[2]) as my result (of course for each row).

If I try your query, I can't have the sum with the previous relations for each node b.

```
START a=node:node_auto_index(name='a')
MATCH path = a-[R*1..3]->b
WITH last(relationships(path)) AS r ,b
WITH r.p1 * r.p2 AS mul,b
RETURN sum(mul),b
```

Clearly, I need to have all the nodes b with the sum of the multiplication of the previous relations.
An idea ? Thanks again.

Comment: In terms of your further post, I have added another query to address your requirement for the sum of every returned path(or every end node of each path). It seems we were over thinking, it actually is much easier than what I thought.

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't think to do p1*p2 in the "extract()". I was really close. Of course, what I want to do is much more complicated than a multiplication. I will have to install Neo4j2.0 for some mathematical functions. My last question : If I want to divide (p1*p2) by the position in the collection (do you follow me?) For instance if there are 2 relations in the path, is there a way to do ((collection_p1[1]*collection_p2[1])/1 + (collection_p1[2]*collection_p2[2])/2) ?